# Decomposition of a Matrix $A$ into $C\cdot\overline{C^{T}}$ form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

> Let $A\in\mathbb{K}^{n×n}$ be hermitian and positive definite.
>
> Show that there exists $C\in GL(n,\mathbb{K})$ for wich
>
> $C\cdot\overline{C^{T}}=A$

While I proved the simpler statement of there being a "Squareroot" for $A$ if $A$ fullfills the given conditions, I have no idea how to tackle this problem. Therefore I would appreciate some hints.

Comment: The spectral theorem implies that $A$ can be written as $UD\overline{U^\top}$ where $D$ is diagonal with positive entries.

Comment: I used that to prove the existence of  a "squareroot", however I didn't see how it would help me here (I'm sure it does but don't know how)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spectral theorem implies that $A$ can be written as $UD\overline{U^\top}$ where $D$ is diagonal with positive entries.
Now take $C=UD^{1/2}$.

Comment: Well, that was simpler than I thought :D Thank you!

Comment: Alternatively, you can look at the algorithm for computing the Cholesky factorization, and use it to constructively prove the existence of the Cholesky factor, which then satisfies the question you ask.